# Quickly accessing matrix element, where indices are given by other matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I am given a matrix `M`. I now need to determine a matrix of the same dimension, which is defined by

`N_{i,j} = M_{A(i,j),B(i,j)}`

for  two matrices `A` and `B` of the same dimension, which define indices.

As an example,

```
set.seed(1)
M <- matrix(LETTERS[1:(4*6)], ncol=6)
A <- matrix(sample(c(1:4), 4*6, replace=TRUE), ncol=6)
B <- matrix(sample(c(1:6), 4*6, replace=TRUE), ncol=6)
```

How do I now quickly determine `N`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
replace(M, TRUE, M[cbind(c(A), c(B))])
```

or

```
array(M[cbind(c(A), c(B))], dim(M))
```